# Encoded params in ngResource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I am trying to pass part of an url (like /one/two/three) as a parameter to a ngResource:

```
angular.module('restapi', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('RESTApi.Generic', function($resource){
        return $resource('/some_action:url', { url: '@url' });
    });
```

which gives a 404 due to my server doesn't understand the transformed url:

```
http://localhost/some_action%2Fone%2Ftwo%2Fthree
```

Is there any way to bypass this behaviour and still use ngResource (and not $http)?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way. By default each parameter is encoded with the following javascript function: [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp).

Why you don't use path like: `/some_action/:firstParam/:secondParam/:thirdParam` ?

Comment: I am passing the last bit of the url as a parameter since I am reading it from somewhere else (I need it to be dynamic). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a quick-fix-workaround:

```
// In angular-resource.js and method encodeUriSegment
  function encodeUriSegment(val) {
    return encodeUriQuery(val, true).
      replace(/%26/gi, '&').
      replace(/%3D/gi, '=').
      replace(/%2B/gi, '+'). 
      replace(/%2F/gi, '/'); // <--- Add this line
  }
```

Refer to https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1388